# mvn eclipse not recognizing src/main/groovy as the source folder

Tags: eclipse, groovy, maven-3, maven-eclipse-plugin

I always have to configure the groovy folders in Eclipse even after I've generated the eclipse project in maven using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` as shown below. Is there a way to tell maven to treat these folders as source folders automatically when generating the eclipse project?

[image]

My plugin definition. I am using [Groovy-Eclipse compiler plugin for Maven](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven)

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>${javac.executable}</executable>
                        <compilerVersion>${javaComplianceLevel}</compilerVersion>
                        <source>${javaComplianceLevel}</source>
                        <target>${javaComplianceLevel}</target>
                        <meminitial>256</meminitial>
                        <maxmem>1024</maxmem>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7.0-01</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                            <!-- Groovy version -->
                            <version>2.0.7-03</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: What groovy plugin are you using for maven?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings added my plug-in def. I am using Groovy-Eclipse compiler plugin for Maven